# Chrome browser width and icon hiding?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, google-chrome, icons

I have windows 7 at work  , chrome version 34 ( latest)

I do see the extension icons as :

[image]

But  , at my home , same chrome version , windows 8 , I see the icons like this :

[image]

**Question**

How can I configure chrome NOT to stack icons ?

*nb changing browser width does NOT affect icons toggling.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chrome remembers these configurations, so you just need to do this once:
When you stand on the border between the star and the extension icons there is an arrow, when you drag it to the right or left it will expand or decrease the place for the extensions. Chrome don't pile them on top of each other when they have place (it'll when you don't give them any space or pull them if you decrease their space).

You need to stand with your mouse in where there is a black circle in the pic:

[image]

Comment: woooo....... didnt know that it's changeable.....tnx (works)